# Express JS - Detect computer bots, spamming

Tags: node.js, web-services, security, firewall

I have tried to search on web but do not get this kind of stuff.
I am looking for expressjs/nodejs framework to identify and block computers/users who are spamming and grabbing data from my server.
I want protect my server from bots. only allowed user 
Are there and best frameworks.

Features like

- Identify
- Block users/ips/networks
- Read pattern

Comment: use a captcha on your front end side if there is one

Comment: @ArpitSolanki bots can use backend directly to call rest APIs.

Comment: You can have a captcha as middleware and store the successful inputs IP address into a whitelist so they are never asked to input it again.  On top of that, have your middleware detect each request to your app.  Detect which ones ping x number of pages in x number of seconds, add those IP addresses to the blacklist.

Comment: Use this as a quick start! https://www.npmjs.com/package/isbot

Answer (score 4):

I use [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban). This system easy to install on any server and have alot of options. For instance, you can protect your ssl.